# Why ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer is issuing tokens to users with ROLE_ADMIN when is it configured only for ROLE_USER?

Tags: spring, roles, oauth-2.0

I am using spring boot application with Oauth2 Security

I have configured ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer to use **client01** client to issue tokens to only users who have **ROLE_USER** like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient("client01")
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .authorities("ROLE_USER")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                    .secret("password")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(1800);
}

curl  -X POST -vu client01:password 'http://localhost:8080/api/oauth/token?username=admin01&password=test&grant_type=password'
```

Why with this client I can also issue tokens to users with **ROLE_ADMIN**?

If I have wrong implementation, what would be the right one?

**My goal is to create two clients:
- one client should allow to authenticate users with ROLE_ADMIN only;
- another client should allow to authenticate users with ROLE_USER only;**

Comment: The authorities are the authorities of the client NOT of the users.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by this?

Comment: Just as I say. You are creating a client with the role `ROLE_USER`. It has nothing to do with what roles the users have. That isn't interesting for a client nor for an OAUth provider. You either grant or don't grant access it has nothing to do with roles.

Comment: Ok, I see. But then I do not understand what is the purpose of configuration .authorities(String... authorities)? These roles that we give to client, what do they do or restrict to this client?

Comment: The client as well as the user have roles. You can use both to authorize as when using OAuth you get an `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` which contains both the user and the oath client credentials.

Comment: Oh wow! You mean I can use just clientid and secret to access my resources? But how without user credentials? For example normally I use this to get token: curl  -X POST -vu client01:password 'http://localhost:8080/api/oauth/token?username=user01&password=test&grant_type=password'

Comment: No. You can write security rules containing both the users and clients roles (or scopes for instance).

Comment: I see, it is just I do not understand what is the difference between clients with different sets of authorities? If we setup client with .authorities("ROLE_USER") what it is restricting him to?

Comment: Nothing. It are only the authorities passed back to the client that is requesting access. The client in the authentication provider is nothing more then a user.